# Chrome thinks there is a scrollbar and ignores 100% width

Tags: html, css

I don't understand why but in Chrome, under specific width it is ignoring the width 100% of the div and is instead showing 100% as if the scrollbars are there.

Other browsers render fine.

I have isolated the issue to be sure no other css was interfering and here is the code:

Please have the following code run on one page:

```
var myTestWindow = window.open("scrollissue.html");

setTimeout(function () {
    myTestWindow.resizeTo(691, 882);
}, 100);
```

and have the scrollissue.html with the following html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <style type="text/css">
        html, body, form
        {
            font-family: 'Segoe UI', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 11px !important;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            overflow:hidden;
        }

        img
        {
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div style="width:100%; height:100%; overflow:auto">
            <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-Ml4Wnl7tF7I/TuMUh7YnM6I/AAAAAAAABSE/wUmg7IbHDrA/s1600/martin-schoeller-george-clooney-portrait-up-close-and-personal.jpg" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

To see the issue sometimes you need to refresh the window that is opened, in my scenario however, it happens many times and happens on a non popup scenario.
I'd like to thank George Clooney for his help on the matter.

Here a screenshot on the img not stretching 100% due to the phatom scrollbar space

[image]

Comment: div with 100% and an img with 100% width? if that deserves a -1 thats really intolerant but ok

Comment: i didn't downvote you. you've got an anonymous downvoter. i just wanted sample code to help out.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try adding

```
* { box-sizing: border-box }
```

or using 100vw instead of %?

Comment: box sizing maintains the same problem. As for 100vw it adds horizontal scrollbars all the time which is undesirable I'm afraid

Comment: Just ruling it out, see my next answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
html {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

I've separated the two because adding overflow-y to html causing two vertical scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

There is 2-3px difference in image height/width you define as window size (I think it's because of browser borders). Set `img { display: block; }` and try next sizes:

```
var myTestWindow = window.open("scrollissue.html");
setTimeout(function () {
    myTestWindow.resizeTo(691, 885);
}, 100);
```

Answer (score -1):

The way to get round this is to add this to your css:

```
html, body {
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: That would show scroll always. the point is chrome is adding scroll space although it doesnt need it

Comment: This is not the solution. OP doesn't always want scrollbars.